# How can I suppress the missing icon densities lint warning?

Tags: android, lint

I get a lint warning when I include an icon which doesn't have versions for different densities. That is, if I add an icon, `myIcon.png`, to the drawable-mdpi directory, lint will complain that I don't have versions of `myIcon.png` in the other drawable directories (drawable-hdpi, -xhdpi, -xxhdpi).

I would like to suppress this warning, either for all icons, or specifically for `myIcon.png`.

What is the syntax I would need to add to my `lint-config.xml` to achieve these suppressions?

example `lint-config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lint>
  <issue id="MissingTranslation" severity="ignore" />
</lint>
```

usage of `lint-config.xml` in `build.gradle` (in my Android mobile):

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        lintConfig file("lint-config.xml")
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply create those images for every density including medium... You should mark some of your previous questions as answered since their advice is accurate.

Comment: Why the down-vote? I think it's a pretty valid question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see this link for graphical designers :

http://developer.android.com/design/style/devices-displays.html

in short , they suggest creating multiple images , one for each of the densities , so that it would look perfect (without pixelation or blurryness) on each of the possible densities.

the sizes should be as followed :

- ldpi - 75% of the original image size
- mdpi - 100% of the original image size
- hdpi - 150% of the original image size
- xhdpi - 200% of the original image size

Comment: One bit of info: if possible, it's best to design your graphics with xhdpi in mind - then scale down for all the others. Should go without saying, but figured I'd note this.

Comment: not exactly (depends on the what he will do) : if he creates xhdpi and simply resizes the images , it doesn't help much for android since it can do the same thing . however , if he uses vector graphics , it should be much better and it won't matter where to start . also ,

Answer (score 5):

Create a lint.xml with the following contents:

```
<!-- Ignore the IconDensities issue in the given files -->
<issue id="IconDensities">
    <ignore path="**/res/drawable-mdpi/myIcon.png"/>
    <ignore path="**/res/drawable-hdpi/myIcon.png"/>
    <ignore path="**/res/drawable-xhdpi/myIcon.png"/>
    <ignore path="**/res/drawable-xxhdpi/myIcon.png"/>
</issue>
```